# Devise with previous encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm currently developing a new application, I had made one in the past and I had done all the users manually but now I'm looking to use the best way possible to implement my users. I had thought in the past of using the gem but because of time reasons I didn't have the time to implement it, now that I'm starting fresh I wanted to start using the gem to optimize and use what the gem has to offer, since I really liked it.

Anyway, my issue is, for security reasons since I will be passing parameters through mobile I will be encrypting the password to pass it to my application, and then with that encrypted password I will encrypt it once again to compare it to the encrypted password, so what I wanted was a way to encrypt the password before devise encrypts it, that way when the mobile app passes the encrypted password it will match to the previous encryption.

I tried a before_save on the Model, without luck, it just saved the encrypted_password empty, I'm not sure why.

tl;dr I need to encrypt before the gem, tried to do it with before_save/before_create on the model but it didn't work, anyone knows any way to do it?

Comment: Let me check I understood you clear.
You'd like to send an encrypted password as a parameter, and then decrypt it and check this is correct?

Comment: Maybe you just need to use HTTPS/SSL connection. It will encrypt all your requests in transport level.

Comment: Not precisely, I'd like to re-encrypt the parameter, for it to match, though, I need to do the same with the web app, I'd like to encrypt my password on my own, and then let Devise re-encrypt it.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following fact: **If you encrypt the password before sending it with a method which allows you to decrypt it at server level, then this means your method is not one-way and the password sent may be decrypted by other person using a middle-man attack. Then you are not safe at all.**

It is much better to use HTTPS/SSL to send this kind of sensitive data. It encrypts all you send at transport level and does this in a way better than anything you can implement by yourself, no offense meant.

Comment: This is the answer. TLS with HTTPS is going to be significantly stronger than anything you cook up on your own. There's no need to encrypt parameters if the connection is properly encrypted unless you're worried about MITM attacks. If you are, you might want to use GPG to encrypt your payload as a precaution, but that's usually a very paranoid thing to do.

Comment: I actually didn't mean this at all, I thought about being able to decrypt it, then it wouldn't be a one-way encryption, I agree. What I thought about, and I believe is different, is encrypting twice, then the encryption of the first encryption should match my encrypted_password, for me to do so, though, I want to be able to do the first encryption before devise encrypts it. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure it is. I just don't know the advantage. You are going to increase complexity without increasing security.

Comment: If I were you I would do a **git clone** in devise repository and take a look into the code to see the exact point where the password is encrypted. Then I would override this method with mine method to perform the task as I needed. Diving deep into Ruby code is always a great way to find this answers and also to learn more Ruby.

Comment: You may implement this "double encription" with Javascript at form level, manipulating the onsubmit event and doing some kind of hash (MD5 is a possibility) before sending the data. But then again... this would increase complexity, but not security.

Comment: I might clone the devise repository, then, and see where the encryption is being made. Thanks a lot, I'm aware that the security wouldn't be increased and that using an HTTPS would probably be better, but I require this for a specific purpose, anywho, thanks.

Comment: Never mind. And when you succeed, if you  remember, post here the result as an answer. It will be useful from the Q&A point of view.

Comment: In the end I think I might end up using my own controllers like I did in the past, I did find where it makes the encryption, but I'm having issues with the override.